# Beginner PL/SQL script. Does this code look correct?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm starting to learn PL/SQL and don't have access to the database currently (so can't check if my code is correct). I'm trying to print out a student's name based on their ID number. So far I have:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  VNAME STUDENT.NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT NAME INTO VNAME
  FROM STUDENT
  WHERE ID = '0123';
  IF SQL%FOUND THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student with ID "0123" has the name ' || VNAME);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Does the syntax look correct? It should generate the output "Student with ID 0123 has the name ____"

Comment: looks correct, but if no record with id = '123' or more than one it will fail. better to add `exception when` clause and catch exception

Comment: Ok, will add that in, thanks.

Comment: You can download and install free version of Oracle database: [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an exception handler, as pointed out in comments, your IF won't work as you expect.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS856

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  VNAME STUDENT.NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT NAME INTO VNAME
 FROM STUDENT
 WHERE ID = ’0123’;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student with ID "0123" has the name ' || VNAME);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No student record found for that id '); 
END;
/
```

Since you don't have access to the DB, here is what your original script will do:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

With the exception handler, in SQLPLUS you'll get:

```
No student record found for that id

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if you donot have access to a database.
You can check your queries over there online.